# how do i webscrape using python and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, syntax-error

Im very new to this, but I have an idea for a website and I want to give it a good go, my aim is to scrape the Asda website for prices and products, more specifically in this case whiskey. I want to grab the name and price of all the whiskey on the Asda website and put it into a nice table on my website, however I am having problems doing so, my code so far is getting syntax error, can anyone help?
the code so far is..

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://groceries.asda.com/shelf/drinks/spirits-ready-to-drink/spirits/whisky/1579926650')

res = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

driver.quit

response = requests.get('https://groceries.asda.com/shelf/drinks/spirits-ready-to-drink/spirits/whisky/1579926650'


whiskey_container = html_soup.find('div', {'class': 'co-product-lazy-container'})

for whiskey in whiskey_container:
    name = whiskey.find('a', {'class': 'co-product__anchor'})
    price = whiskey.find('div', {'class': 'co-product__price'})

    print(name, price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
# for wait time better than time.sleep()
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium import webdriver
import time  # or WebDriverWait
import csv # for saving data in table

# save csv file
def save_csv(dct):
    '''
    dct - dictionary with our data:
                                "cap",
                                "title",
                                "price"

    '''
    name = "file.csv"  # file name, it can choice what you want
    print("[INFO] saving...") # for see that function works
    with open(name, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f: # open file for writing "a"
            # this need for writing data to table 
            writer = csv.writer(f) 
            writer.writerow((dct['cap'],
                            dct['title'],
                            dct['price'],
                        ))

def scroll(driver):
    # for open all interesting us data 
    for i in range(1,6):
        # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,  1000)") 
        time.sleep(7)



driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://groceries.asda.com/shelf/drinks/spirits-ready-to-drink/spirits/whisky/1579926650?facets=shelf%3A1579926650%3A0000&nutrition=&sortBy=&page=0")

for i in range(2): # 2 because we have only two page with data
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30) # or time.sleep(30)
    scroll(driver) # for open all interesting us data

    # get all data to one list in beautifulsoup type
    data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".co-lazy-product-container .co-item")

    # iterating interesting data and create dictionary with data 
    for d in data:
        items = {}
        body = d.text.split("\n")
        items["cap"] = body[0]
        items["title"] = body[1]
        items["price"] = body[-2]
        save_csv(items)

    # pagination
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".co-pagination__last-page").click()

# close driver
driver.quit()
```

Comment: your a genius! this works, I had to change the 'i' for a '_' as i had a pylint error and then all the info come back! if you have time can you talk me through this code as to what each part does, thankyou!

Comment: made some changes

Comment: how did you pick what you wanted from the Asda webpage? im assuming its to do with body[0], body[1] and body[-2] how do i change the code to scrape different information? if possible to select the price as £40.00 for example rather than £ per lt

Comment: You can print body and you will see what data this code scrape

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error, you have ")" missing :

```
response = requests.get('https://groceries.asda.com/shelf/drinks/spirits-ready-to-drink/spirits/whisky/1579926650'
```

it should be :

```
response = requests.get('https://groceries.asda.com/shelf/drinks/spirits-ready-to-drink/spirits/whisky/1579926650')
```

--

btw your code won't work. you have couple of logical errors.
and I doubt you can scrape that page with your current code.

Comment: thankyou for your advice. this is very much a first attempt any way i could fix it, too make it work?